# Create a DataTemplate that contains another DataTemplate which use data source from the first

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext

So, the idea is that I have one `ListView` that uses `Template1` as `DataTemplate`, which then contains another `ListView` of `Template2`, that uses the binding/datacontext of the first ones `Cars`. So the `DataContext` of `Template2`, should be `Template1` `DataContext.Cars` which should be used as bindings for `DataTemplate2`.

Is it possible? And how???

Model:

```
class Reseller 
{
    public Dictionary<int, Car> Cars;
    ...
}

class Car 
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I have two DataTemplates like this:

```
<!--Template1 contains a Dictionary<string, Reseller>-->
<!-- Reseller has another dictionary of Cars like Dictionary<int, Car>-->
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <GroupBox Header="{Binding Key}">
            <ListView x:Name="Internal_Template2
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Template2}"/>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Template1.Value.Cars.Model}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Template1.Value.Cars.Year}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here's a quick drawing of what I want to create. BranchX is a `ListView`, that contains `Cars` which is another `ListView, from Cars property of BranchX:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assigning the *ItemsSource* (I assume you do that in code-behind) in the *ListView*, each item's *DataContext* is set to their model representation. For example:

```
ListView (DataContext: Resellers)
|-- ListViewItem (DataContext: Resellers[0])
|-- ListViewItem (DataContext: Resellers[1])
`-- etc...
```

So you do not need to access the parent *DataTemplate*'s *DataContext*. In fact, The *DataContext* of **Template2** is automatically set to `Resellers[].Value.Cars[]`. This allows you to bind your *TextBlock*s to `Value`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Model}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Year}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
    <GroupBox Header="{Binding Key}">
        <ListView x:Name="Internal_Template2
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Value.Cars}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Template2}"/>
    </GroupBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

You cannot make the *ListView* display its items horizontal in the *ItemTemplate*, you need to add the *ItemsPanel* property to your Reseller *ListView*:

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel
            Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for you contribute. This is quiet simple, and the solution I used. Its brilliant that you can pass the data source too, totally forgot about that! :) I just need to keep in mind that properties need to be public, and type of string or int.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. I'll show you example adapted from my project where I'm using [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) within another ItemsControl. This can be adapted to other containers than ItemsControl, but ItemsControl offers maximum flexibility.
If I understood correctly, you want to display a list of resellers, and for each reseller, you want to display a list of cars.

For each **ResellerInfo** item, the outer ItemsControl will display a StackPanel with a TextBlock and another ItemsControl displaying Cars.

The inner ItemsControl then displays a StackPanel with each car's Model and Year. Notice that the inner's DataContext is automatically set to the instance of **CarInfo**.

As a bonus, we're using VirtualizingStackPanel, which doesn't render items that are off the screen - this can come in handy if your database is large.

The viewmodel which is a **DataContext** of the main control needs to define:

```
public ObservableCollection<ResellerInfo> Resellers
```

**ResellerInfo** is a class that has properties:

```
public String ResellerName
public ObservableCollection<CarInfo> Cars
```

**CarInfo** is a class that has properties:

```
public String Model
public String Year
```

Setters of all properties need to invoke

```
NotifyPropertyChanged();
```

which is defined in [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx%20INotifyPropertyChanged) interface

XAML:

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Resellers}" >
            <!-- Template specifies how this ItemsControl looks like -->
            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="5">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>
            <!-- ItemsPanel holds items. Use it to change the way items are laid out -->
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <!-- ItemTemplate specifies how each item is displayed -->
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- BEGINNING OF SINGLE ITEM CODE -->
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ResellerName}" />
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
                            <!-- Template specifies how this ItemsControl looks like -->
                            <ItemsControl.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="5">
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </ScrollViewer >
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.Template>
                            <!-- ItemsPanel holds items. Use it to change the way items are laid out -->
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <!-- ItemTemplate specifies how each item is displayed. -->
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Year}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                <DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> -->
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <!-- END OF SINGLE ITEM CODE -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

I wrote the code here on StackOverflow so please feel free to correct it if you find mistakes!

Comment: Thanks for your contribute. The solution is without doubt nice with the VirtualizingPanel. I used the example of @hantoun, since the UI is for debugging only, and that example is quiet simple. But your solution with also solve my issue :)

Comment: This solution is better-practice though, compared to the one I posted. I just elaborated on the code you already had.

Comment: @hantoun your solution definitely answers the question better. Actually, I didn't know this can be accomplished with such simple code!